# Comparing AD Group and a CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Im quite new to Powershell and I've hit a brickwall finding information from a CSV. I have an AD Group of users and im trying to find entries that include their samAccountName from a CSV.

The CSV has the headings samAccountname, IP, Subnet and Hostname. For example here is an extract:
*neilp,10.1.52.22,10.1.52.0,Hostname01*

I ultimately need to find all the Hostnames of any samAccountnames in the CSV that are also in the AD Group.

I've been trying the Compare-Object cmdlet but have had no success:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Test_Users = Get-ADGroupMember Test_Users
$Data = Import-csv .\Data.csv

$Data | ForEach-Object {Compare-Object $_ $Test_Users-ExcludeDifferent }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Test_Users = Get-ADGroupMember Test_Users
$Data = Import-Csv .\Data.csv

Compare-Object $Data $Test_Users -Prop sAMAccountName -Include -Exclude | % {
  $account = $_.sAMAccountName
  $Data | ? { $_.sAMAccountName -eq $account } | % { $_.Hostname }
}
```

Comment: That has done the trick! Thanks very much. I needed it so I could move those hostnames to their correct locations in AD so tacked a pipe on the end of your script to complete it. All worked a treat. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving such a problem is to concatenate the two arrays of objects and then use `Group-Object` CmdLet. Just be carefull to have a column header in your CVS with the same name of the propery in the `Get-ADGroupMember` CmdLet.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$a =  Import-csv .\Data.csv
$b =  Get-ADGroupMember Test_Users

$c = $a + $b | group-object -property XXXX
```

Then you can loop through `$c` array to build a new object.